# Semaphore Block Main Process Instead of Multiple Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

So according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx), and many other places I've read, they use a semaphore and block within the individual threads, like so:

```
private static Semaphore _pool;
public static void Main()
{
    _pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Worker));
        t.Start(i);
    }
}

private static void Worker(object num)
{
    try
    {
        _pool.WaitOne();
        // do a long process here
    }
    finally
    {
        _pool.Release();
    }
}
```

Wouldn't it make more sense to block the process so that you don't create potentially 1000s of threads all at once depending on the number of iterations in Main()? For example:

```
private static Semaphore _pool;
public static void Main()
{
    _pool = new Semaphore(0, 3);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
    {
        _pool.WaitOne(); // wait for semaphore release here

        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Worker));
        t.Start(i);
    }
}

private static void Worker(object num)
{
    try
    {
        // do a long process here
    }
    finally
    {
        _pool.Release();
    }
}
```

Maybe both ways are not wrong and it depends on the situation? Or there is a better way to do this once there are a lot of iterations?

Edit: This is a windows service, so I'm not blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you would normally do it inside the thread is you want to make that exclusive section as small as possible. You don't need the entire thread synchronized, only where that thread accesses the shared resource.

So a more realistic version of Worker is

```
private static void Worker(object num)
{
    //Do a bunch of work that can happen in parallel
    try
    {
        _pool.WaitOne();
        // do a small amount of work that can only happen in 3 threads at once
    }
    finally
    {
        _pool.Release();
    }
    //Do a bunch more work that can happen in parallel
}
```

(P.S. If you are doing something that uses 1000 threads, you are doing something wrong. You should likely rather be using a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) or [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) for many short-lived workloads or make each thread do more work.)

---

Here is how to do it with Parallel.ForEach

```
private static BlockingCollection<int> _pool;
public static void Main()
{
    _pool = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    Task.Run(() => //This is run in another thread so it shows data is being taken out and put in at the same time
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
        {
            _pool.Add(i);
        }
        _pool.CompleteAdding(); //Lets the foreach know no new items will be showing up.
    });

    //This will work on the items in _pool, if there is no items in the collection it will block till CompleteAdding() is called.
    Parallel.ForEach(_pool.GetConsumingEnumerable(), new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3}, Worker);
}

private static void Worker(int num)
{
        // do a long process here
}
```

Comment: Ohhh ok. Thanks for your explanation! Yes, in my application I'm using a ThreadPool. In my situation I used a WaitOne on the main thread to prevent it from queuing so many threads all at once because I want to make the processing fair to all users no matter when they add something to the list of items (process one item from each user before moving on to the next item, but do a bunch at a time in parallel). I think it makes sense for this kind of situation (and it's been working), but wasn't sure why it wouldn't for other situations.

Comment: You might be better off using a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to store the queue of work and then use a [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) and set [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) to 3, it gives the same effect of limiting the number of threads and you will have a much lighter workload due to it using less threads.

Comment: This method of having one thread fill a queue of work and another set of threads pull work out is called "The Producer-Consumer Model"

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it! I didn't know there was a name for this method.